# empty drupal commerce cart with a url?

Tags: 7, commerce

Is it possible to empty the cart with drupal commerce by visiting a url?

/cart/empty

Trying to create a test case for selenium

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code would look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['cart/empty'] = array(
    'title' => 'Empty Cart',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), // or whatever permission you want
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_empty_cart',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_empty_cart() {
  global $user;
  // Load the order and empty the cart
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
  commerce_cart_order_empty($order);

  // As this page won't display anything you need to redirect somewhere
  drupal_goto('some/page');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a URL with a callback function in which you just programmatically clear the cart's content.

Comment: Could you provide what that looks like in a module?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but there is now a module for this see [Commerce Empty Cart Paths](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_empty_cart_paths). This module allows site administrators to define multiple paths, and when a user visits a non-declared page, their shopping cart is emptied.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, try [Commerce Empty Cart Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_empty_cart_paths) module.

> It allows site administrators to define multiple paths, and when a
>   user visits a non-declared page, their shopping cart is emptied.
>
> Usage:
>
> 1. Download and enable the module.
> 2. Go to admin/commerce/config/empty-cart-paths and enter any additional paths. checkout, checkout/*, cart and cart/* are declared
>      by default.

Or [combert's sandbox: Commerce Clear Cart](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/combert/2110297) module which simply adds a page that when visited will empty the current users Commerce cart. It also adds a link to that page to the Commerce cart view.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone having the same issue...
I installed Path Rules https://www.drupal.org/project/pathrules.
From there create a custom rule... 
1. Event ->Drupal is initializing
2. check path cart/empty
3. Actions: Remove all products from an order
4. goto Parameter: URL: [site:url]